# Android - Flash - Permission to allow Peer-assisted networking

Tags: android, flash, permissions

I am working on an Android App that implements Flash Peer-assisted networking.

I have normal Android controls and a WebView that includes HTML with an embedded Flash player.

Sometimes the flash player will ask for permission (and everything thereafter works correctly) and sometimes it will not ask and will instead hang. Is there a way I can force the Flash player to ask for permissions? Or a way I can add my App to a list that the Flash player accepts everytime?

As an example, [this is the box](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/images/p2p.gif) that I need to pop up regularly.

Comment: What a shame, that 300 rep is going to float into oblivion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. It was simply due to some HTML markup I had used.

I didn't realise that object tags didn't like being terminated like XHTML designates. Removing /> from the end of the param elements fixed it.